# DirectoryIterator' object has no attribute '_variant_tensor'

Tags: deep-learning

I am working through a tensorflow tutorial to get clued up on using pretrained models and ran into the error

> "DirectoryIterator' object has no attribute '_variant_tensor'"

I am trying to split a validation set into a test and validation set using `tf.data.experimental.cardinality(validation_dataset)`, but end up getting this error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-5818be180afb> in <module>
----> 1 val_batches = tf.data.experimental.cardinality(test_dataset)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\experimental\ops\cardinality.py in cardinality(dataset)
66   """
67 
---> 68   return gen_dataset_ops.dataset_cardinality(dataset._variant_tensor)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
 

AttributeError: 'DirectoryIterator' object has no attribute '_variant_tensor'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image_dataset_from_directory
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        featurewise_center=True,
        samplewise_center=True,
        rescale=2./255)
training_dataset = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'cats_and_dogs_filtered/cats_and_dogs_filtered/train',
        target_size=(160, 160),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        featurewise_center=True,
        samplewise_center=True,
        rescale=2./255)
validation_dataset = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'cats_and_dogs_filtered/cats_and_dogs_filtered/train',
        target_size=(160, 160),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')

val_batches = tf.data.experimental.cardinality(test_dataset)
test_dataset = validation_dataset.take(val_batches // 5)
validation_dataset = validation_dataset.skip(val_batches // 5)
```

Comment: Hello. Welcome to AI SE. Questions about programming issues or bugs are generally off-topic here. Here we focus on theoretical, philosophical and social aspects of AI. See https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for more details. I will migrate this post to Stack Overflow.